# Using eBPF in dpdk

Tags: dpdk, ebpf, bpf

Sorry for some basic question. I understand eBPF in kernel context and use of bpf() system call or helper libraries. How are hooks created in dpdk ? How do we load eBPF code into an already running dpdk application ? I want to have dpdk process expose hooks at multiple places and want to load bpf to dump packets or print stats. I couldn't find all answers or examples of such real world scenarios.

I have gone through the dpdk examples and code implementation but couldn't get the details to actually write an app

Comment: Are you referring to the [BPF integration in DPDK](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/bpf_lib.html)?

Comment: Yes. But how do we load new byte code during runtime ?  Are callback points pre-defined and static in dpdk and we cannot add new ones ?

Comment: I've crafted an answer below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DPDK API for its eBPF module offers the following [generic functions](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__bpf_8h.html):

```
struct rte_bpf *rte_bpf_load(const struct rte_bpf_prm *prm);
struct rte_bpf *rte_bpf_elf_load(const struct rte_bpf_prm *prm, const char *fname, const char *sname);
void            rte_bpf_destroy(struct rte_bpf *bpf);
uint64_t        rte_bpf_exec(const struct rte_bpf *bpf, void *ctx);
uint32_t        rte_bpf_exec_burst(const struct rte_bpf *bpf, void *ctx[], uint64_t rc[], uint32_t num);
```

They allow you to load and execute BPF programs in your DPDK code.

In addition to those, the DPDK library offers [4 functions to attach BPF programs to specific ports & queues](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__bpf__ethdev_8h.html). They will then execute when packets are received and sent on those queues.

```
void rte_bpf_eth_rx_unload(uint16_t port, uint16_t queue);
void rte_bpf_eth_tx_unload(uint16_t port, uint16_t queue);
int  rte_bpf_eth_rx_elf_load(uint16_t port, uint16_t queue, const struct rte_bpf_prm *prm, const char *fname, const char *sname, uint32_t flags);
int  rte_bpf_eth_tx_elf_load(uint16_t port, uint16_t queue, const struct rte_bpf_prm *prm, const char *fname, const char *sname, uint32_t flags);
```

You can find more information in [this presentation](https://www.dpdk.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/35/2018/10/pm-07-DPDK-BPFu6.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the ppt and pointers. I have gone through the code and now understand it.

Comment: Glad if it helped! Please accept the answer if you think it answers your question :-)